# How to find exceptions that can be raised for a particular module in Python?

Tags: python, exception

I would like to know how is the standard way (if there's any) to get the exceptions that a module/function can raised.

Let's take for instance `json`.
Naturally I went to the [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) but I didn't find a standardized way to know which exceptions can be raised in certain functions (like `dump` or `load`). It is not clear to me (at first glance) if just catching `TypeError` will be enough.

Which are the recommendations to be sure that we're catching everything (and just enough) about a particular module/function?

Comment: Also note: the documentation mentions `ValueError` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never been completely satisfied with Python's exception stuff.  It works fine in practice, it's the theory that bothers me. :-)  In particular, because everything is dynamic, even if you know that `evil()` only raises `ZorgError` itself and calls `spam()` which raises `EggsError`, so that at most you get those two errors from a call to `evil()`, someone could patch things behind your back and change this.

That said, some documentation is better than others.  For instance `os.kill` can obviously raise `OSError` if the `kill` fails, and `TypeError` if you call it with something other than two integers, but did you know it can also raise `OverflowError`?

```
>>> os.kill(9999999999999, 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum
```

If you are attempting to write reasonably bullet-proof code that does things like read a pid-file and probe to see if a process is running, it turns out you have to catch this `OverflowError` in case the pid in the pid-file is an integer, but is out of range.  It would be nice if this were in the documentation (I found it through torture-testing instead.)

Simply catching everything (`except:` or `except Exception`) is usually not suitable as it usually catches too much (including, e.g., `RuntimeError` from a stack overflow).  So how do you know what to catch?  I think it might be nice if leaf functions in standard libraries had an "exceptions I raise directly" attribute or documentation-requirement, but it's just not there.

---

Edit: I noted in a comment above that the json documentation mentions `ValueError` explicitly.  Not explicitly called out, but found in json's self tests, are `UnicodeDecodeError` (which is obvious once you think about it) and `AttributeError` (not so obvious).  The documentation also mentions that you can get an `OverflowError`.  Of course, if you use `json.dump`, which takes a stream on which to write, you can get all of the stream's errors as well.  This kind of thing is why a "list of exceptions `zorg()` raises directly" is not always very useful.

Comment: I appreciate your response. It's quite clarifying how one can missed to catch some exception. With that in mind, which is the common Pythonic approach? If it's a function such us `os.kill` catch whatever the documentation states and just leave the corner cases? And for not pretty-well documented modules like `json`, just catch with `Exception`?

Comment: I'm not sure about "common Pythonic".  There are multiple issues to consider.  Sometimes the place to catch a failure is relatively high level, so you just want to let the low level routines fail and pass the error onward.  Sometimes the place to catch a failure is right when it occurs.  Sometimes the object is not to "catch the failure" at all, but rather to clean up (e.g., unlock a data structure), in which case you want a `try` block with a `finally`, or `with` style context manager.  I've found a general consensus, though, that `except Exception` is rarely right.

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use the global type `Exception` to `catch` the `Exceptions`:

```
try:
   1 + "2"
except Exception as error:
   print  "Error", error
```

The output will be something like:

```
Error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

If you want to know the name of that Exception you can do something like:

```
try:
   1 + "2"
except Exception as error:
   print  error.__class__.__name__, error
```

and the output will be something like:

```
TypeError unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a practical way to get exceptions names. The main problem is that I don't have the `code` in advanced to know which exceptions can be raised. I just thought I could find a way to have an exhaustive exceptions documentation about a particular module.

Comment: You're welcome, I think this way is good to catch `Exceptions` because sometimes the doc of a module is bad or sometimes you do not know the kind of `Exception` that a library can raises.